# Typing animation: deleting characters

Tags: ios, swift

Here's a typing animation that adds up characters from an Array to the text of a text field at a fixed time interval:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldMain: UITextField!
var myText = Array("Hi! I'm Cesare.".characters)
var myString = "Hi! I'm Cesare."
var typingAnimationCounter = 0
var typingAnimationTimer: NSTimer?

func fireTimer() {
    typingAnimationTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.05, target: self, selector: "typeLetter", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func typeLetter() {
    if typingAnimationCounter < myText.count {
        textFieldMain.text = textFieldMain.text! + String(myText[typingAnimationCounter])
        typingAnimationTimer?.invalidate()
        typingAnimationTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.15, target: self, selector: "typeLetter", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    } else {
        typingAnimationTimer?.invalidate()
    }
    typingAnimationCounter++
}
```

I would like to have characters of the textField deleted now (like if it was a typing animation, but by deleting characters). I can't figure out how, though.

```
func fireDeletionTimer() {
    typingAnimationTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.45, target: self, selector: "deleteLetter", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func deleteLetter() {
    if typingAnimationCounter < myText.count - 1 {
        let index = myString.characters.count - typingAnimationCounter - 1
        textFieldMain.text = myString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(String(myText[index]), withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
        typingAnimationTimer?.invalidate()
        typingAnimationTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.45, target: self, selector: "deleteLetter", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    } else {
        typingAnimationTimer?.invalidate()
    }
    typingAnimationCounter++
}
```

I thought of replacing every single character with an empty String, but it doesn't work (random letters of the string are replaced). How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not do the following:

```
func deleteLetter() {
    if textFieldMain.text != "" {
        textFieldMain.text = str.substringToIndex(textFieldMain.text.endIndex.predecessor())
    } else {
       typingAnimationTimer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

By the way, if you start your timer with "repeats: true" in `fireDeletionTimer()` you don't need to recreate it again and again in `deleteLetter()`

Also, `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString()` clears every instance of that letter in your text, not just the last one.

Comment: No probs! Also, here's a Swift string operations cheat sheet: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-string-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite the `deleteLetter()` method into something like this:

```
func deleteLetter() {
    myString = myString.substringToIndex(myString.endIndex.predecessor())
    textFieldMain.text = myString

    typingAnimationTimer?.invalidate()
    if myString.characters.count > 0 {
        typingAnimationTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.05, target: self, selector: "deleteLetter", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
}
```

Edit: Looks like Zoltan already beat me to it.